# How can I get a worker thread to execute a callback on the main UI thread?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I want to execute a number of tasks in parallel, once complete I want to execute a callback on the main UI thread. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple threading is not yet currenly supported, Its still under consideration, but there is support for parallel execution using `Async await` (just like in C#).

https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/139

https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/140